# HttpClient 4.3.x, fixing deprecated code to use current HttpClient implementations

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I had the following code, which still compiles, but they're all deprecated:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(context, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
ClientConnectionManager clientConnectionManager = base.getConnectionManager();
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = clientConnectionManager.getSchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, sslSocketFactory));
return new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager, base.getParams());
```

I tried my best to replace it with this portion of the code:

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(context, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
builder.setConnectionManager(new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager());
builder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionFactory);
return builder.build();
```

As you can see, there are few lines of code from the top post that I don't know how to include on the new portion. How can I add needed code, such as, an alternate `SchemeRegistry`?

Comment: Well, the deprecation of SchemeRegistry says "Deprecated. (4.3) use Registry"

Comment: I know that already. How do I use `Registry` since it's a lookup map?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(context, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
builder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionFactory);

Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
        .register("https", sslConnectionFactory)
        .build();

HttpClientConnectionManager ccm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);

builder.setConnectionManager(ccm);

return builder.build();
```

Comment: @Buhake Sindi did you try my answer ?

Comment: I did indeed. I'll need to test though.

Comment: I wouldn't run my code in production since this was to test my OAuth implementation and it is a requirement to include TLS/SSL.

Comment: Where are these classes? `HttpClientBuilder`,`SSLConnectionSocketFactory` `HttpClientConnectionManager ` etc?

Comment: @AlLelopath see the javadoc of the [HttpClient library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 24):

I can not comment yet, but here is a small upgrade to herau's answer since it's deprecated since 4.4, maybe someone will find it useful.

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(context, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: I have this legacy code, `HttpPost request = null;`
`HttpResponse response = null;`

Then at the bottom 
`request = new HttpPost(var);` 
`response = client.execute(request);`

What's the replacement for this?

Answer (score 1):

As manual said, I have replaced library to NoopHostnameVerifier and use it like that:

```
    private static CloseableHttpClient client =
        HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();
```