# Is it possible to pass http response from Java to browser?

Tags: java, browser, apache-commons-httpclient

I got a page by apache HttpClient

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://mywebsite.com");
request.addHeader("User-Agent",  "Mozilla/5.0");

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, localContext);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I need click a link in this page manually

Can I pass the whole response (html, session, cookie) to browser? so that I can complete the remaining process.

Comment: why do you need to do this in both java and browser?

Comment: This will depend a lot on the platform (OS and browser), you should give more details in your question. But I doubt any decent browser will allow you to mess around with their execution context...

Comment: Because some step need to do in program, only last step need to do in browser.

Comment: OS=windows7, Java8, browser=chrome (if I need, I can change other browser)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar question which will get you cookies in Firefox: [Passing Cookies from Java to Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029988/passing-cookies-from-java-to-browser)

As for passing your session, probably not possible although maybe you could do the same thing with the Firefox database. It certainly wouldn't be a "plug and play" solution nor would it be guaranteed to work across versions.

"Passing the HTML" could be done by creating a web server in Java. There are some libraries that you can use for this.

However, all of these things are hacky and will not work in most situations.

An alternative would be to use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) to click the link from within your program, without ever opening a real browser.

Comment: interesting tool, it is very useful in my other programs, but in the case, it is still not enough. Actually in my program, the url is https, so I need set a certificate to httpclient, like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201648/httpclient-4-3-x-fixing-deprecated-code-to-use-current-httpclient-implementatio). And the most important is, this page has many links, links are generated dynamically, I need decide which one I should click, and this logic is very difficult to implement.

Comment: Perhaps you could identify the links using httpclient, print them out in a custom gui, and then based on user input in your own gui click the link using httpclient?